# How To Get Files in Changeset with TfvcChangesetRef

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Using Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK.

How can I get list of files in a changeset?  None of these work...?

```
        var serverUrl = new Uri(url);
        //var clientCredentials = new VssClientCredentials(username, password);
        var clientCredentials = new VssBasicCredential("", accessToken);
        var connection = new VssConnection(serverUrl, clientCredentials);

        var sourceControlServer = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>(); // connect to the TFS source control subpart

        var changesets = sourceControlServer.GetChangesetsAsync(project).Result;
        foreach (var changeset in changesets.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate))
        {
            changeset.Links // this is null
            var items = sourceControlServer.GetItemsByChangesetPagedAsync(
                1000, changeset.ChangesetId).Result;

            var changes = sourceControlServer.GetChangesetChangesPagedAsync(
                changeset.ChangesetId, 1000).Result;

        }
```

Comment: This question can be for the support because the example  [Get a list of changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get_a_list_of_changes) also does not return a list of changed files.

Answer (score 2):

This code works with Azure DevOps Service and nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client 15.131.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/):

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace TFRestApiApp
{     


    class Program
    {
        static readonly string TFUrl = "service_url"; // for devops azure 
        static readonly string UserPAT = "<your_pat>"; //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

        static WorkItemTrackingHttpClient WitClient;
        static BuildHttpClient BuildClient;
        static ProjectHttpClient ProjectClient;
        static GitHttpClient GitClient;
        static TfvcHttpClient TfvsClient;
        static TestManagementHttpClient TestManagementClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            try
            {
                ConnectWithPAT(TFUrl, UserPAT);

                List<TfvcChange> chs = TfvsClient.GetChangesetChangesAsync(344).Result;

                foreach (TfvcChange ch in chs)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ch.ChangeType.ToString(), ch.Item.Path);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null) Console.WriteLine("Detailed Info: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Stack:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }


        #region create new connections
        static void InitClients(VssConnection Connection)
        {
            WitClient = Connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            BuildClient = Connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
            ProjectClient = Connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
            GitClient = Connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
            TfvsClient = Connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();
            TestManagementClient = Connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
        }

        static void ConnectWithPAT(string ServiceURL, string PAT)
        {
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, PAT));
            InitClients(connection);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The result for my repository:

[image]